# Sequence of events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get this to work for months without success. I can get the layers to fade in and out manually by using a separate button "input type='button' value='FadeOut' onclick='fade('Layer1', this)' " for each layer, but getting this to run automatically in sequence had eluded me.

I have six layers, 0-5, that I want to fade in and out in sequence. I then want two functions to run. I want the length of time a layer is visible, approximately one second, to be adjustable. Can someone please help me?

When my page opens, I want "layer0" to be displayed.
onLoad I  want "layer1" to fade in and then out.
Next I want "layer2" to fade in and then out.
Next I want "layer3" to fade in and then out.
Next I want "layer4" to fade in and then out.
Next I want "layer5" to fade in and then out.
Then I want "layer0 to fade out.
Finally I want "function1" and "function2" to run.

Here is the code I am now using:

CSS:

```
.initial-splash {  
    position:absolute;  
    left:10px;  
    top:105px;  
    width:610px;  
    height:335px;  
    z-index: 10;  
 }  
.splash {  
    font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;  
    font-size: 36px;  
    font-weight: bolder;  
    color: #FCC836;  
    height: 49px;  
    line-height: normal;  
    z-index: 12;  
 }  
.splash {  
    display: none;  
}
```

HTML:

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    var delay = 500, speed = 600;
    var layers = $('.splash').length;

    $('.splash').each(function (i) {
        var me = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            me.fadeIn(speed).delay(delay).fadeOut(speed, function () {
                if (i == layers - 1) {
                    $('.initial-splash').fadeOut(speed, animationComplete);
                }
            });
        }, i * (delay + speed * 2));
    });

    function animationComplete() {  
        fade(),hideLayerNext();  
    }  
});  
//]]>  


<div class="initial-splash"><img src="images/Site/625x340sunrise.jpg" alt="sunrise" width="625" height="340" border="1"></div>  

<div class="splash" style="position: absolute; top: 390px; left: 32px; width: 266px; ">Friendship /div>  

<div class="splash" style="position: absolute; top: 324px; left: 147px; width: 236px; ">Fellowship /div>  

<div class="splash" style="position: absolute; top: 256px; left: 265px; width: 189px; ">Recovery /div>  

<div class="splash" style="position: absolute; top: 188px; left: 361px; width: 136px; ">Sanity /div>  

<div class="splash" style="position: absolute; top: 130px; left: 500px; width: 133px; ">Hope /div>
```

Comment: maybe u want to share your code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.delay()` will be helpful here, but it only works on a single element. However, we can combine it with some basic calculations and a setTimeout to make it work for any number of layers:

```
// These are adjustable
var delay = 1000, speed = 600;
var layers = $('.layer').length;

$('.layer').each(function (i) {
    var me = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        me.fadeIn(speed).delay(delay).fadeOut(speed, function () {
            if (i == layers - 1) {
                $('.initial-layer').fadeOut(speed, animationComplete);
            }
        });
    }, i * (delay + speed * 2));
});

function animationComplete() {
    // Do whatever here
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pMnwM/1/

**Update:** I realised that you actually want layer0 to always be underneath the other fade-ins and -outs until the end. Updated my code and demo to work that way.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. It is just what I was looking for. However, I notice that on some computers, an older Mac for example, the animation is not smooth. The layers fade in with random pauses between the first two and then a big delay before the others pop in at once. Is there any way to buffer the process so the timing is more consistent? If you want the URL of the test page I am using this on please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a callback after each fade:

```
$("#layer1").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $("layer2").fadeOut(1000, function() {
       // deeper layers, you get the idea
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with, using callbacks. You can specify the fade delay and the time each layer is displayed.

```
function showHideLayer(id, speed, showFor, callback)
{
    $('#' + id).fadeIn(speed, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut(speed, callback);
        }, showFor);
    });
}

function yourFunction1()
{
    alert('Called Function 1');
}

function yourFunction2()
{
    alert('Called Function 2');
}

$(function() {

    $('#yourlayer1id, #yourlayer2id, #yourlayer3id').hide();

    showHideLayer('yourlayer1id', 2000, 2000, function() {
        showHideLayer('yourlayer2id', 2000, 2000, function() {
            showHideLayer('yourlayer3id', 2000, 2000, function() {
                yourFunction1();
                yourFunction2();
            });
        });
    });

});
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markashleybell/RPs7c/11/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I used the other answer because I apparently was not clear about layer0 being visible until all the other layers fade out.